# Integration: substitution then differentiation result different to differentiation then substitution.

Tags: integration

I want to simplify this derivative ($n$ is an integer)

$$
\frac{d}{d\theta} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{i n \phi} e^{i 2\pi k r \cos(\phi - \theta)}   d\phi
$$

If I substitute $\psi = \phi - \theta$ and $d\psi = 1\,d\phi$ I get
$$
\frac{d}{d\theta} \int_{0-\theta}^{2\pi-\theta} e^{i n \theta} e^{i n \psi} e^{i 2\pi k r \cos(\psi)}   d\psi
$$
Then since the derivatives of the limits are both the same, using the differentiation rule this becomes
$$
\int_{0-\theta}^{2\pi-\theta} i n e^{i n \theta} e^{i n \psi} e^{i 2\pi k r \cos(\psi)}   d\psi
$$

However, if I do the derivative first I get
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi} i 2\pi k r \sin(\phi - \theta) e^{i n \phi} e^{i 2\pi k r \cos(\phi - \theta)}   d\phi
$$
Then substituting $\psi = \phi - \theta$ this becomes
$$
\int_{0-\theta}^{2\pi-\theta} i 2\pi k r \sin(\psi) e^{i n \theta} e^{i n \psi} e^{i 2\pi k r \cos(\psi)}   d\phi
$$

Where am I going wrong? Why are the expressions different?

Comment: I think you forgot to use the chain rule on the part with a $\psi$ in the first case. Note that, with $k,n,r$ fixed and after substitution, your function depends on $\psi$ and $\theta$, so $\frac{df}{d \theta} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \psi} \frac{d \psi}{d \theta}$ by the chain rule.

Comment: @Ian In the first case could I not have moved the $\theta$ part outside the integral - $e^{i n \theta} \int_{0-\theta}^{2\pi-\theta} e^{i n \psi} e^{i 2\pi k r \cos(\psi)}   d\psi$, then evaluated the integral to give $e^{i n \theta} J_{-n}(2\pi k r)$ and then taken the derivative to get $i n e^{i n \theta} J_{-n}(2\pi k r)$?

Answer (score 1):

When you take the derivative before the substitution, you need to apply the chain rule.  $\frac d{dx} e^{kf(x)}=kf'(x)e^{kf(x)}$  When you take the derivative after the substitution, you need to consider how the limits of the integral change as well. Remember the fundamental theorem of calculus:  $\frac d{dx} \int_0^x f(y)dy=f(x)$  There is a term from both the upper and lower limits which you have lost.

Comment: Hi Ross, could you elaborate on your answer as I'm still unclear where the error is. After substitution I used the rule $d/dx (\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x,t)dt) = f(x,b(x))\,b'(x) - f(x,a(x))\,a'(x) + \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f_x(x,t)\,dt$ but since $a'(x) = b'(x) = -1$ the first two terms cancel out.

Comment: Do you know the terms cancel?  Do you know $n$ is an integer?  You didn't say that.  In the derivatives first you need the derivative of $\cos(\phi-\theta)$ as well.

Comment: Yes $n$ is an integer, sorry about that crucial bit of info. That is why they cancel out. I don't see why I need the derivative of $\cos(\phi - \theta)$ as well? Could I not take the $\theta$ part outside the integral, evaluate the integral to get the Bessel function (which doesn't depend on $\theta$) then evaluate the derivative? The $\theta$ in the limits shouldn't matter as $n$ is an integer?

Comment: I fixed the cos in the second part